# How to find ancestor chain of a process?

Tags: linux, unix, process

I can do `ps -o "pid,ppid,args" -p my_pid` to find the parent of `my_pid`.

I can continue `ps -o "pid,ppid,args" -p previously_found_ppid` in a loop until get to `ppid=1`.

However, I bet, there is a single call solution that would start with `my_pid` and list all its ancestors. Something reverse to `pstree` that starts with the parent and list all its descendants. Could you tell whether such Unix/Linux command is readily available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like `pstree` can do what you want, with it's `-s` *Show parent processes of the specified process* option

```
$ pstree -s 5698 
init───mdm───mdm───init───at-spi-bus-laun───dbus-daemon
```

Or more info (arguments) and prettier with the `-a` option

```
mint@mint ~ $ pstree -s -a 5698 
init
  └─mdm
      └─mdm
          └─init --user
              └─at-spi-bus-laun
                  └─dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf ...
```

Or a few options together

```
$ pstree -s -p -a -G -l 5698 
init,1
  └─mdm,1994
      └─mdm,5358
          └─init,5379 --user
              └─at-spi-bus-laun,5691
                  └─dbus-daemon,5698 --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`pstree` can be used to print all the ancestors of a process. But latest Linux distributions uses `systemd` instead of `init`.

Example: `pstree -p -s 6206`  will give following output

```
systemd(1)───lightdm(1066)───lightdm(1191)───upstart(1360)───gnome-terminal-(5222)───bash(5229)───cpu-print(6206)
```

A systemd, may refer to all the packages, utilities and libraries around daemon. It was designed to overcome the shortcomings of init [1].

reference [1]:https://www.tecmint.com/systemd-replaces-init-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Again, using the **Linux** version of `pstree` (macOS version has incompatible options), here's a handy Bash function that prints out the ancestor chain of a process given its PID (if not given, defaults to the current shell process `$$`):

```bash
# show the process chain
# pschain [-n] [-r] [PID]
#  -n: show process names
#  -r: show root of chain (PID 1)
# PID: default is current shell
pschain() {
  local name=0 root=0 pid
  while [[ "$1" == -* ]]; do
    [[ "$1" == *n* ]] && name=1
    [[ "$1" == *r* ]] && root=1
    shift
  done

  pid=${1:-$$}
  pstree -pasTA $pid | \
    awk -v NAME=$name -v ROOT=$root -v PID=$pid '{
      while (match($0, /((\s+\|)*\s*[`|]-)?([^,]+),([0-9]+).*/, a)) {
        pid=a[4]; name=a[3]
        if (ROOT == 0) { ++ROOT; next }
        if (NAME == 1) {
          printf "%-6u %s\n", pid, name
        } else { print pid }
        if (pid == PID) exit
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
      }
    }'
}

$ pschain -nr
1      systemd
104805 tmux: server
104808 bash
105236 gdu-go
105442 bash
```

Since the root of the chain (PID 1) is almost always `systemd`/`init` (unless it's a container process), it's hidden by default, but can be shown using the `-r` option.